# Changing IP address of SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, migration

I administer a Microsoft SQL Server 2012 instance on VMWare, and I need to change the IP address.  Reading similar questions here on the site I am hopeful that the change will be a simple one, but my version in particular hasn't been discussed.

Running SQL Server 2012 on Windows Server 2012 R2, are there any dangers or relevant precautions I should take before changing the IP address?

Comment: SQL Server won't really care if the IP changes. You'll just need to worry about other servers & clients noticing the change--either through DNS updates (and caching problems). And of course, anyplace with an IP hard-coded will need to update to use the new IP.  Do you have any specific concerns, or just your SQL/Windows combination?

Comment: If it is a stand alone you're most likely safe - as @AMtwo said, it will be more on the client side. You'll want a restart of SQL Server to bind to the new address. If it isn't stand alone, please update the question.

Comment: Thank you both.  It is a stand-alone SQL server.  There are a bunch of clients and other servers that talk to it.  If DNS updates are the only concern, that sounds pretty good.  :)

Answer (score 4):

I would say that SQL Server does care when you change the IP address of your server. It is all based on the configuration of the TCP/IP settings for that given instance.

[image]

Once you change the IP, go into SQL Server Configuration Manager and then the Network Configuration. Verify that the new IP was updated properly in the list of IPs for the TCP/IP protocol. If it does not show up, you will likely see the old IP still there, just update it to the new one.

After this you will need to restart the instance.

Comment: I might shorten the TTL of the DNS "A" record for the hostname used by SQL Server hours or days before changing the ip address.  This will help reduce problems with clients trying to connect to the old ip address.  And of course, change the TTL back after the change is stabilized.